# UIImagePicker always issues imagePickerControllerDidCancel in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, image, ios5

So I'm retesting one of my apps that I know works with iOS 4.2 and up on the new iOS 5, and for some reason, they don't want to play nice. My UIImagePicker delegate will, upon the user selecting a photo from the photo library, ALWAYS issue an imagePickerControllerDidCancel, and never allow the picture to be selected (just says the image is nil when I try to load it). This is the code I know works on previous versions of iOS, so I have no idea why it wouldn't work now, unless Apple has changed how UIImagePicker works.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
mainPhoto.image = image;
[self saveImage:image];
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)  picker
{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And here is the code that calls the UIImagePicker:

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Any ideas? Or has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation for
 `-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo` says,

"***Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Use imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: instead.***".Try to follow the suggestion and let us know if you still face issue ?

Comment: This does work! Thank you! However, how do I then do something with the image that was picked? Before I had an image variable that I could then assign to whatever, and now I only have the (UIImagePickerController *)picker and (NSDictionary *)info to do something with.

Comment: @Nathan: first,  try to accept answers - this will motivate us to answer questions :).  Your info is a dictionary that contains image data (and other meta info , if you are interested in).`UIImage* image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
`  shall give you image taken.

Comment: That gives me an image that is 0x0 :/

Comment: @Nathan check this link (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html) clearly explains how to do. " Note: As you do for the camera picker, always call the isSourceTypeAvailable: class method of the UIImagePickerController class and respect its return value. Never assume that a device has a photo library. Even if the device has a library, this method could still return NO if the library is currently unavailable."